# Quickblox Audio call using ear speakers Android

Tags: android, webrtc, quickblox, android-audiomanager

I am implementing  [Quickblox WebRTC calling](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android) . All is successfully implemented, but I want the audio call through ear speakers of the phone. By default, it is only on loud speakers.
How can I enable calling through ear speakers like any other calling app? I also tried this:

```
    AudioManager m_amAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);  
    m_amAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL); 
    m_amAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

But still didn't worked for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To switch the audio socket you need to call the switchAudioOutput(); method on your current version
it switches between the loudspeakers and phone speakers (if the headset is on, then it switches between the headset and the loudspeakers)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But switchAudioOutput(); worked for me only when headset is on. I am unable to reach phone speakers with this method, its still on the loudspeakers. I have used the same method inside a broadcast receiver with Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG intent filter. So when I am plugging headset, it switches audio output. But calling switchAudioOutput(); by default doesn't worked for me!

Comment: Please check if the  AndroidManifest.xml file includes the follofing permission:   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

Comment: yes. I have included this permission as well. But still not working.

Comment: Are you trying to manage audio settings when the session is already active (when the recipient has already clicked on "accept"), or before that? The above mentioned method will work only is connection between two users has been already set.

Comment: It's working. Thanks :) Now I have put it in onConnectedToUser method, and wonders happen!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using QuickBlox SDK version 2.5.2, you can set the AudioManager like this:

```
    audioManager = AppRTCAudioManager.create(this, new AppRTCAudioManager.OnAudioManagerStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAudioChangedState(AppRTCAudioManager.AudioDevice audioDevice) {

        }
    });

    audioManager.setDefaultAudioDevice(AppRTCAudioManager.AudioDevice.EARPIECE);

    audioManager.setOnWiredHeadsetStateListener(new AppRTCAudioManager.OnWiredHeadsetStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onWiredHeadsetStateChanged(boolean plugged, boolean hasMicrophone) {

        }
    });
    audioManager.init();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was using 2.4.